# Sinatra route function call & helpers

Tags: ruby, sinatra

So I have two classes like this.

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
    # don't enable logging when running tests
    configure :production, :development do
      enable :logging
    end

    get '/*' do
        $request = request
        PageController::render
    end
  end
```

and

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
    def self.render()
        @page = Page.find_by permalink: $request.path_info
        if @page then
        else
            halt 400
        end
    end
end
```

All is well, until I reach the halt statement. Method not found. How could I use the Sinatra halt helper from inside this function call?

Comment: Try making `self.render` method an instance method instead of a class method. My guess would be that `halt` is an instance method as well.

Comment: Why is the request being put into a global variable?

Comment: Okay, I see why, because of the class method's scope barring you from using an instance method. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overcomplicated things. See the [Helpers](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) section of docs.

Put this in your Application controller:

```
helpers do
  def render
    @page = Page.find_by permalink: request.path_info
    if @page then
    else
      halt 400
    end
  end
end
```

Now your route will be:

```
get '/*' do
  render
end
```

Still, too complicated if you ask me, no need to ape Rails. Why not keep it simple?

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/*' do
  @page = Page.find_by permalink: request.path_info
  if @page then
    haml :something
  else
    halt 400
  end
end
```

That's it, that's the whole Sinatra app without recourse to inheritance and a structure that isn't required. Unless you're adding pages dynamically after the app is deployed then I'd also define the routes more explicitly.

Don't use globals. I actually can't remember the last time I saw one used, there are so many better alternatives. If you find you need one it's a clue you're going down the wrong path.